# Exponential sums over integers with a fixed number of prime divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Are there bounds in the literature on sums of the form
$$\sum_{\omega(n)= k} e(\alpha n) \;\;\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\;\; \sum_{\Omega(n)=k} e(\alpha n)$$
for $\alpha$ on minor arcs (i.e., not very close to a rational with small denominator)?
It's not hard to prove such bounds given things that are standard and available, but I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's so interesting. I'm not sure whether the best bounds for the sums would be obtained using sieve methods, power series methods, or Dirichlet series methods. They just seem so prone to being analyzed.

Comment: M. Radziwill has pointed me towards Tenenbaum, "Facteurs premiers de sommes d'entiers".

Comment: Tenenbaum's article has an answer. One can give a sharper estimate by supplementing his procedure with a contour integration as in Selberg-Delange.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I couldn't get over the fact that $e(\alpha n)$ is not multiplicative with respect to $n$, however, so that didn't get me anywhere.